# Weld CDI: how to make one bean class satisfy any of multiple qualifiers?

Tags: code-injection, cdi, jboss-weld, qualifiers

From reading the Weld docs I don't think this can be done, but I could really do with it, so thought I'd ask - if there's not a way with CDI, maybe there's a pattern workaround...

I've created a custom qualifier with a member:

```
@Qualifier
@Target({TYPE, METHOD, FIELD, PARAMETER})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface JobBinding {
    JobType value();
}
```

JobType is an enum:

```
public enum JobType {

    JOB_A,
    JOB_B,
// etc - there are quite a few
```

Say most jobs need building in a slightly different way, so I have builder classes related to the jobs. These are annotated with a JobBinding annotation given the relevant JobType:

```
@JobBinding(JobType.JOB_A)
public class JobABuilder implements JobBuilder {
....
```

When I need to build, I use programmatic lookup:

```
@Inject @Any
private Instance<JobBuilder> builderSource;
private JobType myJobType;
...
builderSource.select(new JobBindingQualifier(myJobType).get();
```

JobBindingQualifier is a custom class:

```
public class JobBindingQualifier extends AnnotationLiteral<JobBinding> implements JobBinding {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -822150300665931157L;

    private JobType type;

    public JobBindingQualifier(JobType type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    @Override
    public JobType value() {
        return type;
   }
}
```

So far, great - CDI working brilliantly. However, what if 2 of these jobs, JOB_X and JOB_Y, are built in exactly the same way? I only need one builder class, which I'd like to be instantiated for either of those options - `new JobBindingQualifier(JobType.JOB_X)` or `new JobBindingQualifier(JobType.JOB_Y)`.

If I annotate `JobXAndYBuilder` with both `@JobBinding(JOB_X)` and `@JobBinding(JOB_Y)`, I get a compiler error about the duplicated annotation. To get around this I could change the value of the annotation to an array of JobTypes, and you would annotate the builder like

```
@JobBinding(JobType.JOB_X, JobType.JOB_Y)
```

with the constructor called there using an ellipsis to produce the array. However, if I did that, how could I look that up programmatically using *either of the jobTypes*? Weld docs suggest that you would have to have *both*; I'd need to provide the exact arguments:

```
builderSource.select(new JobBindingQualifier(JobType.JOB_X, JobType.JOB_Y).get();
```

when I want either to be sufficient to lookup the class:

```
builderSource.select(new JobBindingQualifier(JobType.JOB_X).get();
//or
builderSource.select(new JobBindingQualifier(JobType.JOB_Y).get();
```

Using the array really just changes the value that you have to match when looking up. I really need a way of annotating a class twice with the same qualifier annotation, and then being able to look it up with any combination of them. Otherwise I'll have to provide a builder class each for X and Y, when one would suffice. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you want to lookup for either of the jobTypes it's not the right way to proceed. Putting 2 qualifiers on a bean is an AND qualification not an OR. Is this problem still pending ? I think I have a solution and will take time to write it down if you still need it.

Comment: Yes please! Very much still valid!

Comment: Sorry, Stack overflow don't seem to have found mail notification concept :-). My answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in my comment there is no straight way to have an OR relation when you have two or more qualifiers on a bean class.

So the solution to have the same Bean with another qualifier is to use the Producer mechanism. In your example you can create you first class as usual :

```
@JobBinding(JobType.JOB_X)
public class JobABuilder implements JobBuilder {
    ....
}
```

and after that create a producer method in either in the first class or in a dedicated producers class like that

```
public class MoreJobsProducer {
    @Produces
    @JobBinding(JobType.JOB_Y)
    protected JobBuilder prodJobYBuilder(@New @JobBinding(JobType.JOB_X)
                                         JobBuilder theJob) {
        return theJob;
    }    
}
```

In the paramaters of the producer method you Inject your former bean with its own qualifier and the `@New`qualifier which create a new instance of the bean to be sure you avoid some scoping issues (read the Weld doc for more info).

It should do the "Job".

Comment: Ahhh - thanks Antoine, cunning! Great idea. 

I can see that it would work if you did `@Inject @JobBinding(JobTYpe.JOB_Y) JobBuilder myYJobBuilder;`, but I'm not sure about `builderSource.select(new JobBindingQualifier(JobType.JOB_Y).get();` - does the Instance stuff use Producers as well, or would it still be expecting an actual annotated class...? 

I'll give it a go and find out, anyway - thanks a lot!

Comment: It works. I use it in Seam Social to allow inject of Twitter services and associated settings in two ways. If you have issues let me know